# How to alternate between requests ensuring fairness in Celery?

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I am using celery to run long running tasks(~20mins per task). Whenever a user submits a request, I schedule ~10 tasks in celery for that user. So a single request from a user takes 200 mins to complete. The problem arises when an another user submits a request. The second user's tasks wait till all of the tasks issued by the first user completes. My question is, is there a way to alternate between these two users.

Current Scenario: User A(10 tasks), User B(10 tasks) ..

Execution Sequence: A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B

Desired Sequence: A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B

I run my tasks like so.

```
run_task.delay(user_id_here)
```

Also, the above scenario is not limited to two users. I have kept it that way for the sake of simplicity. Also, because of memory constraints, I can only spawn a single celery worker. So spawning a dynamic worker for each user won't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to [route](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) your users tasks (randomly) on separate celery workers using different queues. This may not give you exactly the same desired behviour but it will reduce tasks wait time.

in terminal:

```
$ celery -A my_app worker -l info  -c 1 -n my_worker1 -Q queue1
$ celery -A my_app worker -l info  -c 1 -n my_worker2 -Q queue2
$ celery -A my_app worker -l info  -c 1 -n my_worker3 -Q queue3
```

in your **tasks.py**:

```
selected_queue = select_queue() # select_queue is function that you may implement yourself to change each time between the queues
my_task.apply_async(args=my_args, queue=selected_queue)
```